# access to function - ORA-00904: invalid identifier

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am new to oracle, please assist.

I have written a function similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338198/how-do-you-get-the-next-value-in-a-sequence-into-a-variable) in schemaB, with minor alterations.

When I run the query from above function, in schemaA, it runs fine and returns the sequence.

```
select schemaB.sequence_name_seq.nextVal from dual;
```

Running the function from schemaB ofcourse return the sequence as expected.

However, when I try to access the same function (containing the above query) from schemaA, it gives me an error:
"ORA-00904: invalid identifier"

I have granted EXECUTE privileges to userA of schemaA (confirmed from 'DBA_TAB_PRIVS' table).

Function:

```
create or replace Function nextSeq
(
   tableName in VARCHAR2
)return NUMBER as
nextNum Number;

begin

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select '||tableName||'_SEQ.nextval from dual' into nextNum;

return nextNum;
END nextSeq;
```

To Call:

```
select nextSeq('SCHEMAB.TABLENAME') from dual;
```

Comment: added the function too.

Comment: updated. Yes, its a seq, though I am passing tableName and appending _SEQ to get the sequence name.

Comment: Trying to put AUTHID CURRENT_USER after nextSeq and also before return, but getting error..."expecting ( or RETURN expected, got AUTHID"

Comment: Tried, create or replace Function nextSeq
(
   tableName in VARCHAR2
)return NUMBER AUTHID CURRENT_USER as.. it completed, but still get the same error while running from other schema.

Comment: Perhaps this is just a learning exercise, but from Oracle 12.1 onwards you can use identity columns and stop micromanaging named sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I'd do that: connected as `SCOTT`, I'm creating a sequence and a function; then I'll grant `EXECUTE` on the function to user `MIKE`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create sequence dept_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace function nextseq (tablename in varchar2)
  2    return number
  3  as
  4    nextnum number;
  5  begin
  6    execute immediate 'select ' || tablename||'_seq.nextval from dual' into nextnum;
  7    return nextnum;
  8  end;
  9  /

Function created.

SQL> select nextseq('dept') from dual;

NEXTSEQ('DEPT')
---------------
              1

SQL> grant execute on nextseq to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Connect as `MIKE` and use `SCOTT`'s function:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@xe
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> select scott.nextseq('dept') from dual;

SCOTT.NEXTSEQ('DEPT')
---------------------
                    2

SQL>
```

As you can see it *works*. When compared to your code, the difference is here:

```
You: select nextSeq('SCHEMAB.TABLENAME') from dual;
Me : select scott.nextseq('dept') from dual;
```

You shouldn't precede *table name* with the owner, but the *function name*.

Comment: SPOT ON!! it works now. Thanks a tonne for giving a detailed explanation along with pointing out difference in calling the function.